# Midpoint ellipse algorithm in 8086 Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, graphics, x86-16

I'm trying to implement an ellipse drawing algorithm with 8086 Assembly in VGA (320x200) mode, but the shape is not drawing properly for bigger radii.

[image]

As you can see the shape is concave or straight not elliptical. I get acceptable result when the axis have small lengths i.e (10, 15) but any more then that and it stops resembling an ellipse. I used an FPU to calculate all values.

```
    .387

SCREEN_WIDTH = 320
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200
HALF_SCREEN_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
HALF_SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2

stack1 segment stack
            dw 300 dup(?)
stack_top   dw ?    ;stack_top pointer

stack1 ends

code1 segment
start1:
    mov ax,seg stack1 
    mov ss,ax                               ; initialize stack
    mov sp, offset stack_top

    mov al, 13h     
    mov ah, 0       ; change mode
    int 10h         ; enter graphics mode

    mov byte ptr cs:[color], 10
    
start_draw:
    call clear_screen
    call ellipse

wait_key:
    in  al, 60h ;take keyboard input
    cmp al, 1   ;if ESC end
    je end_program
    jmp wait_key

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------
x_radius            dw 40   ;width of the ellipse
y_radius            dw 50   ;height of the ellipse

x_derivative        dw ?    ;derivates calculated from ellipse equation
y_derivative        dw ?

x_squared           dw ?    ;squared values for convenience
y_squared           dw ?

decision_param      dw ?    

four                dw 4    ;int values used in some of the expressions
two                 dw 2    ;storing them so I can load them to the FPU
;----------------------
calc_x_derivative:
;x_derivative = 2 * y_squared * x
;RPN: 2 y_squared x * *
    finit
    fild    word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fimul   word ptr cs:[two] ;instead of multiplying by 2 
    fimul   word ptr cs:[x]
    fistp   word ptr cs:[x_derivative]
    ret
    
calc_y_derivative:
;y_derivative = 2 * x_squared * y
;RPN: 2 x_squared y * *
    finit
    fild    word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fimul   word ptr cs:[two] 
    fimul   word ptr cs:[y]
    fistp   word ptr cs:[y_derivative]
    ret

ellipse:
    ;initialize x as 0 and y as y_radius
    mov     word ptr cs:[x], 0
    mov     ax, word ptr cs:[y_radius]
    mov     word ptr cs:[y], ax

x_radius_squared:
    finit 
    fild    word ptr cs:[y_radius]
    fimul   word ptr cs:[y_radius]
    fistp   word ptr cs:[y_squared]

y_radius_squared:
    finit
    fild    word ptr cs:[x_radius]
    fimul   word ptr cs:[x_radius]
    fistp   word ptr cs:[x_squared]

derivatives:
    call calc_x_derivative
    call calc_y_derivative
    
calc_decision_param_1:
;d1 = y_squared - (x_squared * ry) + (1/4 * x_squared)  
;RPN: y_squared x_squared ry * - x_squared 4 / +
    finit
    fild    word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fild    word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fild    word ptr cs:[y_radius]
    fmul
    fsub
    fild    word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fidiv   word ptr cs:[four]
    fadd
    fistp   word ptr cs:[decision_param]

region_1_loop:
    call color_all_symmetries

    inc word ptr cs:[x] 
    call calc_x_derivative

    cmp word ptr cs:[decision_param], 0 ;compare decision_param to 0
    jge region_1_alternative_next       ;if its lower decrement y and calculate alternative decision_param

region_1_next:
;decision_param = decision_param + x_derivative + (y_squared)
;RPN: decision_param x_derivative + y_squared +
    finit
    fild word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    fild word ptr cs:[x_derivative]
    fadd
    fild word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fadd
    fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    jmp region_1_loop_end

region_1_alternative_next:
;decision_param = decision_param + x_derivative - y_derivative + (y_squared)
;RPN: decision_param x_derivative + y_derivative - y_squared +
    dec word ptr cs:[y]
    call calc_y_derivative
    finit
    fild word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    fild word ptr cs:[x_derivative]
    fadd
    fild word ptr cs:[y_derivative]
    fsub
    fild word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fadd
    fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]

region_1_loop_end:
    mov ax, word ptr cs:[x_derivative]
    cmp ax, word ptr cs:[y_derivative]     ;check if x_derivative < y_derivative
    jge calc_decision_param_2              ;if it is we are done with region 1
    jmp region_1_loop

calc_decision_param_2:
;decision_param = (y_squared * (x + 1/2) * (x + 1/2)) + (x_squared * (y - 1) * (y - 1)) - (x_squared * y_squared)
;RPN: y_squared x 1 2 / + * x 1 2 / + * x_squared y 1 - * y 1 - * + x_squared y_squared * -
    fild word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fild word ptr cs:[x]
    fld1
    fidiv word ptr cs:[two]
    fadd
    fmul
    fild word ptr cs:[x]
    fld1
    fidiv word ptr cs:[two]
    fadd
    fmul
    fild word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fild word ptr cs:[y]
    fld1
    fsub
    fmul
    fild word ptr cs:[y]
    fld1
    fsub
    fmul
    fadd
    fild word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fimul word ptr cs:[y_squared]
    fsub
    fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]

region_2_loop:
    call color_all_symmetries

    dec word ptr cs:[y]
    call calc_y_derivative

    cmp word ptr cs:[decision_param], 0 ;check if decision_param < 0
    jge alternative_region_2_next

region_2_next:
;decision_param = decision_param + x_squared - y_derivative
;RPN: decision_param x_squared + y_derivative -
    finit
    fild word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    fild word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fadd
    fild word ptr cs:[y_derivative]
    fsub
    fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    jmp region_2_loop_end


alternative_region_2_next:
    inc word ptr cs:[x]
    call calc_x_derivative

region_2_alternative_decision_param:
;decision_param = decision_param + x_derivative - y_derivative + (x_squared)
;RPN: decision_param x_derivative + y_derivative - x_squared +
    finit
    fild word ptr cs:[decision_param]
    fild word ptr cs:[x_derivative]
    fadd
    fild word ptr cs:[y_derivative]
    fsub
    fild word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fadd
    fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]

region_2_loop_end:
;y_derivative = y_derivative - (2 * x_squared)
;RPN: y_derivative 2 x_squared * -
    finit
    fild word ptr cs:[y_derivative]
    fild word ptr cs:[two]
    fild word ptr cs:[x_squared]
    fmul
    fsub
    fistp word ptr cs:[y_derivative]

    cmp word ptr cs:[y], 0      ; check if y <= 0
    jg region_2_loop       

end_ellipse:
    ret

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;---------------------  color_pixel  -------------------------

x       dw ?
y       dw ?

temp_y  dw ?
temp_x  dw ?

color   db ?
;---------------------
color_all_symmetries:
    ; Coloring points (xc + x, yc + y), (xc - x, yc + y), (xc + x, yc - y), (xc - x, yc - y)
    push ax

    ;Point (xc + x, yc - y)
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_HEIGHT
    sub ax, word ptr cs:[y]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_y], ax
    mov ax, word ptr cs:[x]
    add ax, HALF_SCREEN_WIDTH
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_x], ax
    call color_pixel

    ;Point (xc - x, yc - y)
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_HEIGHT
    sub ax, word ptr cs:[y]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_y], ax
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_WIDTH
    sub ax, word ptr cs:[x]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_x], ax
    call color_pixel

    ;Point (xc + x, yc + y)
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_HEIGHT
    add ax, word ptr cs:[y]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_y], ax
    mov ax, word ptr cs:[x]
    add ax, HALF_SCREEN_WIDTH
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_x], ax
    call color_pixel

    ;Point (xc - x, yc - y)
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_HEIGHT
    add ax, word ptr cs:[y]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_y], ax
    mov ax, HALF_SCREEN_WIDTH
    sub ax, word ptr cs:[x]
    mov word ptr cs:[temp_x], ax
    call color_pixel

    pop ax
    ret

color_pixel:
    push ax
    push es
    ;position needs to be in a format y*320 + x
    mov ax, 0a000h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, word ptr cs:[temp_y]    ;selecting a row
    mov bx, SCREEN_WIDTH            
    mul bx                          ;ax multiplying y by 320 to get proper position
    mov bx, word ptr cs:[temp_x]    ;selecting a column
    add bx, ax                      ;adding to the pixel position
    mov al, byte ptr cs:[color]     ;adding a color
    mov byte ptr es:[bx], al

    pop es
    pop ax
    ret
;-------------------------------------------------------------


end_program:
    mov al, 3h
    mov ah, 0
    int 10h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

clear_screen:
    mov ax, 0a000h
    mov es, ax
    xor ax, ax
    mov di, ax
    mov cx, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT
    mov al, 0
    cld
    rep stosb   ;while cx != 0, mov byte ptr es:[di], al; di++; cx--
    ret

code1 ends

end start1
```

I tried many different version of the same algorithm all to no success. I think it might be an issue with my variables(especially the derivatives and decision parameter) overflowing I tried fixing it by using `double words` instead of `words` to declare variables but I had trouble comparing them later in the algorithm, and when I did get the program to compile it still did not work as intended.

Comment: Do you intentionally use the FPU instead of a Bresenham-style algorithm (see e.g. http://members.chello.at/~easyfilter/bresenham.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it might be an issue with my variables(especially the derivatives and decision parameter) overflowing

Your suspicion about variables overflowing is correct.
As an example, consider the computation for *calc_decision_param_1*:

> ```
> ;d1 = y_squared - (x_squared * ry) + (1/4 * x_squared)
> ```

The result for this is (50 * 50) - (40 * 40 * 50) + (40 * 40 / 4) = -77100
This doesn't fit a signed word anymore and therefore the `fistp word ptr cs:[decision_param]` instruction can't but store the default 'IntegerIndefinite value 8000h' in the word-sized destination.

What you should do is defining some of your variables as dword integers: *x_derivative*, *y_derivative*, and *decision_param*. All other variables will fit their current word size.

> but I had trouble comparing them later in the algorithm

The code that checks whether `decision_param < 0` should simply look at the sign bit of the dword variable:

```
test byte ptr cs:[decision_param+3], 80h
jz   alternative_region_2_next
```

And the code that checks whether `x_derivative < y_derivative` could use `ficomp` to compare these signed dword integers. Based on the (conflicting) comments (`;check if x_derivative < y_derivative` and `;if it is we are done with region 1`), it would look like:

```
  fninit
  fild    dword ptr cs:[x_derivative]
  ficomp  dword ptr cs:[y_derivative]
  fnstsw  ax
  sahf
  jb      calc_decision_param_2   ; done if x_derivative < y_derivative
  jmp     region_1_loop

calc_decision_param_2:
```

---

It would seem that `x_radius_squared:` and  `y_radius_squared:` do exactly the opposite from what their names tell us!